# Summarizing Table on 2 fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, statistics, census

I have a table of Census Blocks linked to ZIP4 values. I'm trying to create another table getting the unique ZIP4 values associated with each Census Block.

I've tried using the Frequency, and Summary Statistics tool. These give me what I need, but the ZIP4 values are all added up, I need them separately.

Would using Pivot Tables get me what I need?

Using ArcMap 10.2.2, all extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add a new text field
2. Using Field Calculator concatenate the block name field with the ZIP4 field - python e.g. `str(!blockName!) + ' ' + str(!ZIP4!)`
3. Right click on the step 1 field and select Summarize (keep defaults).

This should give you a summary table of all block names by ZIP4 values.